# jQuery CSS position right not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an a div with `position:absolute`. I'm trying to position it to right using jQuery but it's not working. In the code below i'm basically removing left and adding right:0. This should position the div to far right. using firebug, i can see the inline style being changed to `right:0`  but nothing is happening. What am i doing wrong. **Check http://jsfiddle.net/SJP3b/1/**

```
$('div').css({
    left: '',
    right: 0
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `left:'auto'` that works for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/SJP3b/2/

Many values can't be set to blank.
So you have to set them to their default css value.

That's `auto` for the `left` attribute:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_left.asp

Comment: i do not need to have both left and right. I don't understand why removing left is not making this work.

Comment: You're not removing `left`. You're setting it to a blank value, which isn't being evaluated at all. `left: auto` is the default value for `left`, which *does* reset it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `'0px'`

```
$('div').css({
    left: '',
    right: '0px'
});
```

EDIT 1:

Sorry, For `position:absolute` property you can use `left` and `top` property. it not about jquery.

Comment: No jQuery takes care of that.

Comment: You do not need px if it's 0.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if right is a valid css key.  if it is

```
$('div').css({
    left: auto,
    right: 0
});
```

Should work...

You can also check `float:right`